# Websites for online all-vs-all tournaments

Tags: tournament, online-chess

We have a small chess club with about 15 people, whereof about 6 - 10 people comes every week.
We play a blitz tournament where everyone meets everyone.

During corona, we do not meet physically, and the problem being that we don't know how to host the tournament where everyone meets everyone exactly once. Technical knowledge is very limited for some players, so managing the scoring manually is not an option.

Is there any website that offers this type of tournament? All we can see is where tourneys has x rounds and swiss pairing system.

Comment: I sadly do not know if there is a site that easily supports that type of tournament but maybe I can offer an alternative: Our chess club had the same problem, and they decided to just try out Lichess.org's tournament-system: You play the tournament for a set amount of time (p.e. 2 hours) and when you finish your match, you get matched immediately when someone else finishes. People really enjoyed it, even though it is a different format. Lichess is free and has one of the cleanest playing UIs I have seen so far, which might be a plus for the less tech-savy members of your club.

Comment: The arena format of lichess, mentioned by @BenjaminRaabe is a fun idea, but not close to what you're requesting.  Lichess does allow you to create your own tournament and only allow your club register, but that's still not what you requested.  Lichess suggests that you create the RR tournament on another site/chat room and have the players challenge the appropriate opponent on lichess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I don't know of any such site, but I also manually conduct tournament in my small group( 12 members) via Lichess.

Just manually draw a Swiss tournament and setup a Discord for your club. announce the pairings and format and the players can decide the time of play with their opponents. collect the results and repeat the same for the next round.

Edit : Lichess is adding a Swiss tournament feature ([source](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/pull/6551))

Answer (score 1):

I know a site where you can create tournaments with your rules:

www.lichess.org

I play myself with many other people's there. Try it.
Lichess has this game mode already